# Swagger-UI and GitHub Pages (gh-pages)

Tags: github-pages, swagger-ui

Has anyone reading this board have Swagger-UI up and running on GitHub Pages?

I got as far as displaying the Swagger-UI main page, but the Try-it-Out feature does not work.

Comment: Define "does not work". Are there any errors in the browser console?